# Make a math vector class to be initializer list aware

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I have a math vector class that is designed as follows:

```
class Vector3D {
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

public:
    Vector3D() {}
    Vector3D(float xx, float yy, float zz = 0.0) { x=xx; y=yy; z=zz; }
    Vector3D(const float v[]) { x=v[0]; y=v[1]; z=v[2]; }
    Vector3D(const Vector3D& v) { x=v.x; y=v.y; z=v.z; }

    // math member methods
    // ...
};
```

I used to use the following to create a Vector3D-type variable on the stack:

```
Vector3D vec1 = Vector3D(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

I heard a can shorten this up with C++0x by implementing an initializer list constructor, so it will be possible to write something like:

```
Vector3D vec1 = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
```

What is the right way to implement this?

#### Update

The curly braces syntax really works out of the box for this class! Thanks for the answer and the comments!

Also, I did some synthetic performance tests trying to measure if constructor initializer list gives a speedup over member variable assignment in a constructor. Below is the results I've got with g++ 4.6.1:

1. As is (member assignment in a constructor & custom copy constructor):

   ```
   Median:       634860 ns
   Median, CPI:  15.8715 ns
   Average:      636614 ns
   Average, CPI: 15.9154 ns
   ```
2. Using constructor initializer list & custom copy constructor:

   ```
   Median:       634928 ns
   Median, CPI:  15.8732 ns
   Average:      636312 ns
   Average, CPI: 15.9078 ns
   ```
3. Using constructor initializer list & default copy constructor:

   ```
   Median:       860337 ns
   Median, CPI:  21.5084 ns
   Average:      864391 ns
   Average, CPI: 21.6098 ns
   ```

**Some of the conclusions:**

- The constructor initializer list does not give a speedup over member variable assignment in the case of the math vector class presented above.
- The custom copy constructor is more than 35% faster than the default copy constructor.

Comment: You can already write:

    `Vector3D vec1(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);`

You still want to use an initializer-list?  Actually, an initializer-list assignment operator is probably a lot more helpful than an initializer-list constructor.

Comment: With C++11's uniform-initialization syntax, you can already write `Vector3D vec1{1.0, 1.0, 1.0};` with your current class definition. What good would an initializer list do? @Ben : `vec1 = {2.0, 2.0, 2.0};` would already work as-is for assignment as well.

Comment: It's a bit soon to think about initializer-list constructors when you haven't even got constructor-initializer lists down. Say `Vector3D(float xx, float yy, float zz = 0.0) : x(xx), y(yy), z(zz) { }` at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brace-initialization works for all sorts of constructors, and you don't need an initializer-list constructor argument in this case. On the contrary, initializer lists are for *variable* content, like the content of a dynamic container, but not for fixed-length constructor arguments. So you can just say:

```
vector3D v { 1, 1, 1 };
```

and all will be fine.

Note however that you should really initialize your class members rather than assigning them:

```
Vector3D(float xx, float yy, float zz = 0.0) : x(xx), y(yy), z(zz) { }
Vector3D(const float v[]) : x(v[0]), y(v[1]), z(v[2]) { }
```

You also shouldn't write a copy constructor, since it does no better then the one that's provided by default. The same goes for the assignment operator.

(Personally, I don't feel comfortable with the `float[]` constructor; it'd be better to use a `std::array<float, 3>`; but then again you might just use such an array as your 3D-vector type from the start and not bother writing a custom class at all.)

Finally, you can combine construct-initializer-lists and initializer-list-constructors in this last example of making a list of vectors:

```
std::list<Vector3D> l { { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, { 1.5, 3.0, 4.4 }, { 0.0, -1.2, 4.1 } };
```